# Disable autocomplete on Firefox for Android

Tags: firefox, android

I'm trying to get more control over the technology I use, and I would like to disable all the autocomplete activity that happens in the **Firefox mobile** browser for **android**.

There is a setting called `browser.urlbar.autocomplete.enabled`, but it doesn't seem to do anything when you set it to `false` - the urlbar still autocompletes with pages I have previously visited, favorites, previous searches etc.

**I would like to completely prevent this behavior** - a blank search bar that makes no suggestions and just searches for what you type, or if you type a URL it navigates to it.

This seems to be hard!

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An imperfect answer but it kind of works:

1. Prevent Firefox from remembering any history by following [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157768/how-to-disable-browsing-history-in-android-firefox-fennec?newreg=1140dc14c1b44087a2b1b11debed3cfd):

> Go to `about:config`. Create a new boolean value (+ icon) called
> `places.history.enabled` and set to `false`.

2. remove all your bookmarks; depending on how your homepage is set up, they might be quite hard to get at. I had to [change my homepage](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-firefox-home-screen?redirectslug=customize-firefox-homepage&redirectlocale=en-US) by tapping `menu` > `settings` > `general` > `home` and then showing the bookmarks button, then going to the bookmarks page and manually deleting all bookmarks, and then hiding the bookmarks button again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to switch these settings to `false` on the about:config page:

- browser.urlbar.suggest.bookmark
- browser.urlbar.suggest.history
- browser.urlbar.suggest.openpage
- browser.urlbar.suggest.searches

I still get suggestions for bookmarks that have a keyword configured, but other than that it seems to work fine.

See also: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1173445

**Note**: This seems to work only on desktop versions of Firefox.

Comment: I do not have those settings. Do I have to create them?

Comment: I suppose so. Although I already have them, and I'm sure I never created them. Using FF 70

Comment: I am on Firefox 68.1.1 

Perhaps I should try updating it through the play store?

Comment: I see, you're on Android, I missed the tag, sorry. Maybe that's the difference. I have only tried on Windows 10.

Comment: you also missed the word "Android" in the Title ;-0